# Qt5: Name in Taskbar unknown whereas window title is correct

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I set the window title by

```
QWidget::setWindowTitle("test");
```

so the title of the window is "test". But in the taskbar it's displayed as "unknown". What's the correct way to set the taskbar name?

Edit:

I use Gnome3.4.2 and just found https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22274. But for me there also the binary name isn't displayed; only "unknown".

EDIT2:

I tried it under Xfce and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not installed libgtk dev packages when compiling Qt. Make sure you have libgtk dev packages are installed and try compiling Qt5 again.

Comment: I looked after libgtk-dev and it wasn't installed, so i installed it and recompiled Qt but without success.